# data visualization tools for apache cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-visualization

What are free tools for Apache Cassandra data visualization, with drag and drop function?
I worked with `Apache Zeppelin` and `Kibana`, any suggestion except those, pls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to connect Tableau (famous data visualization tool) with Cassandra. There is an intermediate layer which is the Spark Thrift Server (so you need a Spark cluster). The whole setup requires a bit of effort but is doable. You can easily find some tutorials / blog post on the internet, that will explain you how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, If you mean Tableau Public, It released just for Windows and Mac OS and unfortunately my OS is Linux!

Comment: You can install tableau in a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox)

Comment: I want to use it in production environment not just for test. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you want to be "production", then tableau server (Linux available), or tableau online is what you should be looking at.